# Oracle SQL query performance optimization of rpad and decode functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am heavily using the `rpad` and `decode` [Oracle SQL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19188_01/doc/B15917/sqfunc.htm) in a CSQL file which is used to make a SQL*Plus call.

I am wondering if there is any way to optimize the following SQL query for performance.

```
select 
    rpad(decode(someStringColumn1, null, 'foo1', someStringColumn1), 8) ||
    rpad(decode(someStringColumn2, null, 'foo2', someStringColumn2), 5) ||
    rpad(decode(someStringColumn3, null, 'foo3', someStringColumn3), 16) || 
    rpad(decode(someDateColumn1, null, ' ', to_char(someDateColumn1, 'YYYYMMDD')), 8) ||
    rpad(decode(someDateColumn2, null, ' ', to_char(someDateColumn2, 'HH24MISS')), 6) ||
    lpad(decode(someDateColumn3, null, ' ', to_char(someDateColumn3, 'FF3')), 3) ||
from someTable;
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `decode` over `nvl` here? And the last three don't really need to be padded as you're specifying the format already. But not sure you'd see any measurable performance difference from changing those.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for the ideas! I will replace  `rpad(decode(someDateColumn1, null, ' ', to_char(someDateColumn1, 'YYYYMMDD')), 8)` with `decode(someDateColumn1, null, '        ', to_char(someDateColumn1, 'YYYYMMDD'))` which should improve performance since it removes a function. And yes I assume `NVL` would probably be faster than `decode`. Let me do some testing and get back to you, or if someone else can do some testing that would be great;-)

Comment: `decode` performs faster than `nvl` [reference](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7806711400346248708)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rarely any need to optimize built-in SQL functions used in a query.  SQL tuning is mostly about access methods, join methods, and join orders.  The functions used on the data normally only add a trivial amount of time to queries.

It's more important to worry about how the data is retrieved.  There's usually not much that can be done with a select statement without any predicates.  Here are some possible
 ideas to explore, but don't be surprised if none of them help.

1. Create an index on all the relevant columns.  Then Oracle can scan the smaller index instead of the table.
2. Use parallelism to scan a large table faster.  But parallelism is deceptively simple.  A hint like `select /*+ parallel */ ...` may be all you need.  But there are many
   ramifications of that change.
3. Shrink the table.  For example, table compression can make the table much smaller.  But this also has consequences.

Comment: Wow! Using Oracle's Parallel Execution feature (Option 2 above) did the trick! It cut my execution time in half!

Comment: Choosing as answer because of [Oracle's Parallel Execution feature](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/usingpe.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Other tip and trick is to ensure that you run stat on your table and index. Oracle optimizer rely on stat to define it access path. If stat is not run oracle will perform slow period.

Comment: I am a developer and not a DBA. The best I can do is pass this information onto the DBA and hope they do this. Thanks for the insight though!

Comment: With only one table and no predicates there's really not much for optimizer statistics to do in this case.